# “its something of” vs “something of it”

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, possessives

I am bit confused between  the Possessive adjective and Preposition

> I got a car from India for my brother and its one wheel are made from Germany.
>   I got a car from India for my brother and one wheel of it made from Germany.

My concern is which sentence is correct in the view of the position  "its one wheel" and "one wheel of it".

Answer (score 1):

Neither is idiomatic, nor grammatical

"Its one wheel was made in Germany" implies "It has one wheel", and "This wheel was made in Germany".  The subject is singular, so you can't use the plural verb "are". The making of the wheel is in the past, so I've used a past tense verb.

"One wheel of it was made in German"  Is closer to what you probably mean. Again you need the correct form of the verb "was made". It means that the car had several wheels, one is German.

A more idiomatic way to say that is "One of its wheels was made in Germany". Notice that this is also a singular subject and so the verb is "was" not "were" or "are".